# Query FQL event table for events in a specific time range

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, facebook-fql

i use FQL in order to fetch events information from facebook on android .

i need to take events that are 1 week before today and 1 week after today .

i've tried the next code , but it seems that `DATEADD` is a function that doesn't exist on FQL :

```
final Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "fql.query");
params.putString("query",
    "SELECT eid, update_time, start_time, end_time, creator, description, name, location " + 
    "FROM event " + 
    "WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() AND rsvp_status != 'declined') " + 
    "AND start_time<DATEADD(day,7,now()) AND start_time>DATEADD(day,-7,now())");
final String response = "{\"data\":" + _facebook.request(params) + "}";
final JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
final JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
```

what can i use instead of `DATEADD` ?

another problem i've found is that they say on the [**facebook API**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) that the `start_time` field is a string , which is weird by itself ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok , i've found the solution:

```
final Bundle params = new Bundle();
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
final String startTime = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
final String endTime = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
params.putString("method", "fql.query");
params.putString("query",
    "SELECT eid, update_time, start_time, end_time, creator, description, name, location " + 
    "FROM event " + 
    "WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() AND rsvp_status != 'declined') " );
        + "AND start_time<'" + startTime + "' AND start_time>'" + endTime + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it seems that DATEADD is a function that doesn't exist on FQL

Nope, it doesn’t. So compute the appropriate date value yourself in your app, and put it into the query.

> another problem i've found is that they say on the facebook API that the start_time field is a string , which is weird by itself ...

What’s “weird” about that? An ISO-8601 date can not be expressed as a numeric value, and to have a special “date” data type for this would bring no benefit while using FQL.

Comment: _“So compute the appropriate date value yourself in your app, and put it into the query.”_

Comment: yes, but how? i know how to create date-related classes and get the current date and date before&after the current date . what should be changed in the FQL query itself with this data ? no matter what i've tried , none of the classes made a working query (all gave an error) . the question is about the FQL query .  i do not need for facebook to give me all of the events , only those that are of interest for the app . i know i can fetch all and then check the time , but that's not what i need to do.

Comment: The date format of the FQL `event` table is documented – so where exactly is your problem now just putting a date string in that format into your query?

Comment: i've updated my code . please tell me what's wrong with it . i really tried many things.